# Using *if* AND *whether* in the same phrase

Tags: writing-style, conjunctions, if-whether

I am wondering **if** one could use *if* and *whether* in the same phrase or **whether** it is better to use two identical conjunctions.

Comment: It might help if you add an example or two of how you want to use these together.

Comment: You just ***did*** use *if* and *whether* in the same phrase (twice in fact), and it made sense (both times) …

Comment: @JasonBassford was it correct? Or should I have used two *if*s (*whether*s)? Could I use two *if*s (*whether*s)? - alternation seems more natural to me, but I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: As personal preference, in this circumstance, I would be inclined to use the two different conjunctions, to avoid repetition.

Comment: An example, please.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, however you should be aware of the [difference between them](https://www.google.com/search?q=if+vs+whether&oq=if+vs&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l2.4752j0j7&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: You probably mean ' ... in the same sentence'. And your self-referential example complicates the issue as a 'word as a word' is merely a noun, a list item. This sentence 'uses' _aardvark_, _fo'c's'l_, _interosculate_,  _altruistic_ and _plutonium_, as well as _if_ and _whether_.

Comment: _If_ the R number comes below 0.5, and _if_ hospitals seem to be coping well, the Government will relax the quarantine rule. // Whether we go or whether we stay won't make a great deal of difference. //// The answer depends largely on the sentence in question, and partly on the formality level required. Like @Christina, I'd use your version, here, though with major tweaks. I'd class _if_ and _whether_ here as complementisers, for a start. And replace 'phrase'.

Comment: @BillJ My question is an example. Sorry for trying to be cute.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. It is a different question, but what is wrong with *phrase*?

Comment: Are you claiming that 'if' and 'whether' are in the same _phrase_ in the following string? ● I am wondering if one could use the two words in question in the same phrase or whether it is better to use two identical complementisers.

Comment: A [phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/phrase.htm) refers typically to a grouping of words which typically do not contain a subject or verb. What you are calling a phrase is in actual fact a [clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/clause.htm) which typically contains a subject and a verb.

Comment: All other things being equal, "whether" is preferred in formal style, so I wouldn't mix 'n' match formal and informal style. Incidentally,  "if" and "whether" belong to the word class (part of speech) 'subordinator' (or more precisely 'interrogative subordinator').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see your point. It is just another artifact of being non-native: I remind myself every time that in US we do not say *sentence* but *phrase*... but this is colloquial speech. In a somewhat academic discussions in this forum *sentence* has precise meaning and would be actually appropriate here.

Comment: Don't worry about the (here) irrelevant distinction between clause and phrase. It's way off-topic. Focus on the question of using "whether" and "if" in the same expression.

Comment: Don't be misled into thinking that the structure that is being referred to is irrelevant here. Or into thinking that it is unimportant not to point out major errors / potential areas of confusion; others reading the thread may think ELU contributors sanction such terminology, analysis. This is counter to the principles ELU is intended to adhere to.

Comment: Absolute nonsense! Of course it's irrelevant. The OP was not asking for a commentary on the structure of their question, but about using "if" and "whether" in the same expression. There is no confusion whatsoever in the OP's question, and in any case the term 'phrase' was not used in a grammatical way (i.e. in contrast to 'clause') but in a general non-grammatical way. There's nothing wrong with it. @Vadim just ignore the pedantic nit-picking comments.